# How to display microbit's orientation as a 3d model in processing?

Tags: processing, port, communication

I am working on a project with my rocketry club.
I want to have a microbit control the orientation of the fins to auto-stabilize the rocket.
But first, I tried to make a processing code to display in real-time my micro-bit's orientation using its integrated gyroscope.

Here's my processing code :

```
import processing.serial.*;  // import the serial library

Serial myPort;  // create a serial object

float xRot = 0;  // variables to store the rotation angles
float yRot = 0;
float zRot = 0;
String occ[];
void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P3D);  // set the size of the window and enable 3D rendering

  String portName = Serial.list()[0];  // get the name of the first serial port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);  // open a connection to the serial port
  println((Object[]) Serial.list());
}

void draw() {
  background(255);  // clear the screen
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);  // center the cube on the screen
  rotateX(xRot);  // apply the rotations
  rotateZ(yRot);
  rotateY(zRot);
  fill(200);  // set the fill color
  box(100);  // draw the cube
}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
  // this function is called whenever new data is available
  // read the incoming data from the serial port
  String data = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');  // read the data as a string
  // print the incoming data to the console if it is not an empty string
  if (data != null) {
    println(data);
  }
  delay(10);
  if (data != null) {
    // split the string into separate values
    String[] values = split(data, ',');
    // convert the values to floats and store them in the rotation variables
    xRot = radians(float(values[0]));
    yRot = radians(float(values[1]));
    zRot = radians(float(values[2]));
  }
}
```

and here's the python code I have on my microbit

```
pitch = 0
roll = 0
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

def on_forever():
    global pitch, roll, x, y, z
    pitch = input.rotation(Rotation.PITCH) + 90
    roll = input.rotation(Rotation.ROLL) + 90
    servos.P2.set_angle(pitch)
    servos.P1.set_angle(roll)
    x = input.rotation(Rotation.PITCH)
    y = input.rotation(Rotation.ROLL)
    z = 1
    serial.set_baud_rate(BaudRate.BAUD_RATE115200)
    serial.write_string(str(x) + "," + str(y) + "," + str(z) + "\n")
basic.forever(on_forever)
```

What happens when I run my code is that a cube appears and rotates weirdly for a short time, then, the cube stops and processing prints "Error, disabling serialEvent() for COM5 null".

Please help me out, I really need this code to be working!

Comment: At first glance it appears that there is a problem with data transmission from the microbit, which I have no experience with.  Would it be possible to get code working first with an Arduino UNO and then translate it to the microbit?  I do know that Processing's SerialEvent is pretty picky and it doesn't take much to cause an error.

Comment: In serialEvent() do a println() on the data string and the values array to make sure that your app is getting the numbers that you think it should be getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this the documentation](https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/input/rotation) for the micro:bit Python API you're using ?

`input.rotation` (as the reference mentions), returns accelerometer data:

> a number that means how much the micro:bit is tilted in the direction you ask for. This is a value in degrees between -180 to 180 in either the Rotation.Pitch or the Rotation.Roll direction of rotation.

I'd start with a try/catch block to get more details on the actual error.
e.g. is it the actual serial communication (e.g. resetting the baud rate over and over again (`serial.set_baud_rate(BaudRate.BAUD_RATE115200)`) instead of once) or optimistically assuming there will be 0 errors in serial communication and the string will **always** split to at least 3 values.

Unfortunately I won't have the resources to test with an actual device, so the following code might contain errors, but hopefully it illustrates some of the ideas.

I'd try simplifying/minimising the amount of data used on the micropython (and setting the baud rate once) and removing the need to read accelerometer data twice in the same iteration. If z is always 1 it can probably be ignored (you always rotate by 1 degree in Processing if necessary):

```py
pitch = 0
roll = 0
x = 0
y = 0

def on_forever():
    global pitch, roll, x, y
    x = input.rotation(Rotation.PITCH)
    y = input.rotation(Rotation.ROLL)
    pitch = x + 90
    roll  = y + 90
    servos.P2.set_angle(pitch)
    servos.P1.set_angle(roll)
    serial.write_string(str(x) + "," + str(y) + "\n")

serial.set_baud_rate(BaudRate.BAUD_RATE115200)
basic.forever(on_forever)
```

On the processing side, I'd surround serial code with try/catch just in case anything went wrong and double check every step of the string parsing process:

```java
import processing.serial.*;  // import the serial library

Serial myPort;  // create a serial object

float xRot = 0;  // variables to store the rotation angles
float yRot = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P3D);  // set the size of the window and enable 3D rendering

  String portNames = Serial.list();
  println(portNames);

  String portName = portNames[0];  // get the name of the first serial port
  try {
    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);  // open a connection to the serial port
    myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  } catch (Exception e){
    println("error opening serial port " + portName + "\ndouble check USB is connected and the port isn't already open in another app")
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
}

void draw() {
  background(255);  // clear the screen
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);  // center the cube on the screen
  rotateX(xRot);  // apply the rotations
  rotateZ(yRot);
  fill(200);  // set the fill color
  box(100);  // draw the cube
}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
  try{
    // this function is called whenever new data is available
    // read the incoming data from the serial port
    String data = myPort.readString();  // read the data as a string
    // print the incoming data to the console if it is not an empty string
    if (data != null) {
      
      println(data);
      
      // cleanup / remove whitespace
      data = data.trim();
      // split the string into separate values
      String[] values = split(data, ',');

      if (values.length >= 2){
        // convert the values to floats and store them in the rotation variables
        xRot = radians(float(values[0]));
        yRot = radians(float(values[1]));
      }else{
        println("received unexpected number of values");
        printArray(values);
      }
      
    }
    
  } catch (Exception e){
    println("error reading serial:");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
    
}
```

(If the above still produces serial errors I'd also write a separate test that doesn't use the servos, just in case internally some servo pwm timing/interrupts alongside accelerometer data polling interferes with serial communication for some reason.)

(AFAIK there is no full IMU support on the micro::bit (e.g. accelerometer + gyroscope + magnetometer (+ ideally sensor fusion)), just accelerometer + magnetometer. If you want to get basic rotation data, but don't care for full 3D orientation of the device should suffice. Otherwise you'd need an IMU (e.g [BNO055](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor) or newer) which you can connect to the [micro via I2C](https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/pins/i2c-write-buffer) (but will also probably need to implement the communications protocol to the sensor if someone else hasn't done so already).(In theory I see there's Python support for the Nordic nRF52840 chipset, however microbit uses nRF51822 for v1 and nRF52833 for v2 :/). Depending on your application you might want to switch to a different microcontroller altogether. (for example the official [Arduino 33 BLE](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/nano-33-ble-sense) has a built-in accelerometer (and Python support) (and even [supports TensorFlow Lite](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-33-ble-sense/get-started-with-machine-learning)))

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have a microbit I tested your Processing code using an Arduino UNO at 9600 baud rate.  The following serialEvent() function runs without error:

```
void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
  String data = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); 
  if (data != null) {
   String inStr = trim(data);
    String[] values = split(inStr, ',');
    printArray(values);
    // convert the values to floats and store them in the rotation variables
    xRot = radians(float(values[0]));
    yRot = radians(float(values[1]));
    zRot = radians(float(values[2]));
  }
}
```

**Arduino code:**

```
byte val1 = 0;
byte val2 = 0;
byte val3 = 0;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
 val1 += 8;
 val2 += 4;
 val3 += 2;
 String s = String(String(val1) + "," + String(val2) + "," + String(val3));
 Serial.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much George Profenza, it works perfectly well now!
I just had to fix some errors in the code.
Here's the functional code if anyone has this problem later :

```
import processing.serial.*;  // import the serial library

Serial myPort;  // create a serial object

float xRot = 0;  // variables to store the rotation angles
float yRot = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P3D);  // set the size of the window and enable 3D rendering

  String portNames[] = Serial.list();
  printArray(portNames);

  String portName = portNames[0];  // get the name of the first serial port
  try {
    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);  // open a connection to the serial port
    myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    println("error opening serial port " + portName + "\ndouble check USB is connected and the port isn't already open in another app");
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);  // clear the screen
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);  // center the cube on the screen
  rotateX(xRot);  // apply the rotations
  rotateZ(yRot);
  fill(200);  // set the fill color
  box(100);  // draw the cube
}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
  try {
    // this function is called whenever new data is available
    // read the incoming data from the serial port
    String data = myPort.readString();  // read the data as a string
    // print the incoming data to the console if it is not an empty string
    if (data != null) {

      println(data);

      // cleanup / remove whitespace
      data = data.trim();
      // split the string into separate values
      String[] values = split(data, ',');

      if (values.length >= 2) {
        // convert the values to floats and store them in the rotation variables
        xRot = radians(float(values[0]));
        yRot = radians(float(values[1]));
      } else {
        println("received unexpected number of values");
        printArray(values);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    println("error reading serial:");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

As for the Micro:Bit, I didn't have to change the code at all...

I assume their was an error with the Z axis since we basically just removed removed that...